# Tensorflow: Training models with graphs that won't fit into memory of a single GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, out-of-memory

The `MemoryError` is raised when building the graph, and before anything will be transferred to the GPU. The `MemoryError` is caused by trying to allocate more memory than the machine has available.

- What I have: Multiple GPUs
- What I don't have: Not large enough memory to fit the graph on any single GPU
- What I want to do: Train the model in a single GPU in several passes, or even better, use all the GPUs simultaneously to train different parts of my model (if that's even possible).

But how do I train a model which requires a massive graph to be loaded into the memory (which it won't fit into)? Training in parts? Freezing layers? A quick google search does not give any hints at all :/

**What is the right and perhaps the best way to do this?**

Comment: This is a broad subject in general. Training can be split across GPUs, machine clusters etc and there are many large scale platforms. But I think for a concrete example using multiple GPU's you can look at the [cifar10 example](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py). Around line 170, multiple GPUs are assigned to different parts of the computation graph. Also, [read this](https://medium.com/syncedreview/how-to-train-a-very-large-and-deep-model-on-one-gpu-7b7edfe2d072)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Totally possible!

Different parts of you graph can be assigned to different GPUs (and CPU).  Inspired by [Using GPUs](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/using_gpu), you ought to be able to do something like:

```
`with tf.device('/device:GPU:2'):`
    a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
    b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3, 2], name='b')

`with tf.device('/device:GPU:1'):`  
    c = tf.matmul(a, b)
```

Ops and tensors can be arbitrarily assigned to CPUs and GPUs (be mindful, of course that your performance can be affected significantly by having to shuffle a lot of data between different pieces of hardware).

Furthermore, [Distributed Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/distributed) allows you to assign ops and tensors around multiple systems on a network and takes care of the plumbing for you.